# Solve for $x$: $ x \arctan(x) =0.5$

Tags: trigonometry

For a given variable **y**, I want to solve for **x** for this equation: $ x \arctan(x) = y $

For discussion, we can set $y = 0.5$ if that helps.
An accurate approximation is fine, I would prefer up to 16-decimal accuracy if possible.

$$ x \arctan(x) = 0.5 $$

Using Excel and some guessing I can see that the answer is approximately $0.765378926665789$, but I want to be able to calculate this quickly when changing the variable y.
I don't know how to solve for x, I've tried and failed at what I'm sure is easy to do. Thank you in advance for the help.

**EDIT:** based on the solution provided by Ahmed Aattaala I created some Excel VBA code just in case someone wants to play around with this in a simple language environment.

Function xATAN(ByVal y As Variant) As Variant
    ' Solves for x for the equation: y = x ATAN(x)
    Dim a, x As Variant
    Dim i As Single
    x = y
    Do
        a = x
        x = a - ((a * Atn(a) - y)) / ((a) / (a^2 + 1) + Atn(a))
        i = i + 1
        DoEvents
    Loop Until x = a Or i > 1000
    xATAN = x
End Function

Comment: Do you need a perfectly mathematical way to solve this (as we use in an exam)?

Comment: Can you do it by graphing (I mean is it allowed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say we find an solution $x$ to your equation then:

$$x \arctan (x)=0.5$$

But

$$(-x) \arctan (-x)=  --x \arctan (x)=0.5$$

So $-x$ is also a solution.

Use newtons method to find $x$

$$f(x)=x \arctan (x)-0.5$$

$$f'(x)=(1)\arctan (x)+ x(\frac{1}{x^2+1})$$

Let $x_1=.5$

And

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac {x_n \arctan (x_n)-0.5}{\frac{x_n}{x_n^2+1}+\arctan (x_n)}$$

Then we have

$$x=\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \approx 0.765378926665788882856647721092667904$$

And $-x$ is also a solution. Note though that really isn't a nice closed form for $x$ for all $y$.

Easy way on your calculator to compute the limit of this sequence if you have an $\text{Ans}$ button:

1. Type $0.5$
2. Press $=$
3. Type $\text{Ans}-((\text{Ans} \arctan (\text {Ans})-0.5) \div ((\text{Ans}) \div (\text{Ans}^2+1)+\arctan (\text{Ans})))$
4. Repeatedly click $=$ until it appears the number in your calculator is not changing.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for the help! This solution here was very easy to iterate through and I am surprised at how quickly high precision is achieved. With just 6 iterations it already had 15 decimal precision.

Comment: For those who'd like to solve this using something simple like Excel, I'll show how. Cell A1 = 0.5; Cell A2 =A1 - ((A1 * ATAN(A1) - A\$1)) / ((A1) / (A1^2 + 1) + ATAN(A1)); then copy A2 downward to A3, A4, etc. and you'll see the answer refine to closer precision rapidly. Notice how A1 becomes A2, then A3... except for the A\$1, which will stay pointed at A\$1. I hope this helps for those who are new to using Excel.

Answer (score 2):

Graphing for the functions and searching for solutions we have this-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can use this way
$$x \arctan(x) = 0.5$$

$$x=\frac{0.5}{\arctan(x)}$$
$$x=\frac{0.5}{\arctan (\frac{0.5}{\arctan (\frac{0.5}{\arctan ...})}}=0.765378926665789$$

Comment: You have give a complicated continued fraction....is there any way to solve this without a calculator?

Comment: @tatan I think there is no way to solve it without using a calculator

Comment: Then,I think graphing might be a better option...

Comment: @tatan but how you can solve it graphically to get   a high accuracy

Comment: In this type of problems approximations is a must....no method can give the exact answer...you will always have a few more decimal digits to add after your answer to make if more perfect....you will have to continue infinitely by adding a few more numbers....this reminded me of a quote by G.H. Hardy-"We are merely explorers of infinity in our pursuit for absolute perfection"....

Comment: @E.H.E  I tried this before but it converged extremely slowly matter of fact it almost appeared to be alternating.

Comment: FYI if this converges, then this method is called fixed point iteration

Answer (score 1):

"Bisection" is a perfectly good method.  Letting f(x)= x arctan(x), with x= 0, f(0)= 0(0)= 0< 1/2 and with x= 1, f(1)= (1)arctan(1)= 1.4801> 1/2.  Since f is a continuous function, there exist a value of x between 0 and 1 such that f(x)= 1/2.  We don't know where between 0 and 1 but we can try [b]half way[/b] between.  f(1/2)= (1/2)arctan(1/2)= 0.2318.  That is less than 1/2 so there must exist a root between 1/2 and 1.  Halfway between them is 3/4.  f(3/4)= (3/4)arctan(3/4)= 0.2318.  That's less than 1/2 so there exist a root between 3/4 and 1.